# Where do i have to start the service 'rackup' for sinatra while using rvm on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sinatra, rvm, rackup

i am developoing an webapp in the IDE rubymine on ubuntu and i recently installed the gem sinatra for my gemsets to write an REST-API for my webapp. I have a little start problem because i dont know where i should write the 'rackup' command after i created the app.rb and config.ru. My ubuntu doesn't know rackup because of rvm. It tells me i should install ruby-rack but isn't sinatra supposed to have it on board? Is it a problem if the gem rack 2.0.1 is also installed in the same gemset?

I have tried to start rackup with the system terminal. It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your sinatra rack simply by loading your sinatra app with ruby in the command line:

```
=>ruby app.rb
```

A *config.ru* file is only necessary if you're trying to do something weird with rack or are deploying your app to Heroku or some other service which handles its own rack.